# tensorflow datasets found a different version of the requested dataset

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I loaded the imagenet2012 datasets according to the instructions on tensorflow datasets for imagenet2012, and it produced a directory storing the tfrecords under imagenet2012/5.0.0.

But when I reload the dataset, it says

WARNING:absl:Found a different version of the requested dataset: 5.0.0
Using /datasets/imagenet_tar/imagenet2012/5.1.0 instead.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you launching as `tfds.load('imagenet2012')` ? Or `tfds.load('imagenet2012:5.0.0')` ? Which `tfds.__version__` version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run as `tfds.load('imagenet2012:5.1.0')`, the error message should go away